# How to swap element on screen with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple 'li' elements:

```
$(".my_lis")
```

with on the page I want to shuffle them around with JavaScript (I'm using JQuery). How to do that?

Comment: When you say shuffle do you mean randomly mix their order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not too hard actually.  The general idea is:

1. Grab all the dom nodes
2. Shuffle them
3. Empty the `<ul>` and insert the shuffled nodes

--

```
var items = $('.my_list li').get();

//edit (per comments): avoid confusion
items = shuffle(items);

$('.my_list').empty().append(items);
```

Where shuffle() can be anything that shuffles the array, I prefer underscore.js but here is a vanilla JavaScript way of doing a shuffle on an Array:

**Just an example on shuffling ANY array**

```
function shuffle(items) {

    for(var index = 0, ln = items.length; index < ln; index++) {
        var item = items[index],
            swapIndex = ~~(Math.random() * ln),
            swapItem = items[swapIndex];

        //Swap places
        items.splice(swapIndex, 1, item);
        items.splice(index, 1, swapItem);
    }

    return items;
}
```

Comment: technically, you don't have to assign it.  Arrays are passed by reference in JS.

Comment: Where does `index` from `items.splice(index, 1, swapItem);` come from?

Comment: Note that you don't have to empty the list; when you append a node that's in the DOM to a new parent, it is automatically removed from the old location.

Comment: @Phrogz That is interesting ;p I didn't know that.  I'm excited to try this out.

Answer (score 3):

A reliable option is to insert a temporary dummy element after each element in the jQuery collection, then shuffle the current collection, and replace the elements in the dummy collection with elements from the shuffled list.

When appending a DOM element to another place, the element is automatically removed from the previous place.

### Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ryEHm/2/

Code:

```
var $collection = $(".my_list li");
var shuffled = [];
$collection.each(function() {
    shuffled.push(this); //Push DOM element
}).after('<span class="dummy"/>');

$('span.dummy').each(function(index) {
   $(this).replaceWith(shuffled.splice(Math.random()*shuffled.length),1);
});
```

Comment: Note that my answer applies to elements located anywhere, not *just* for consecutive elements.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this plugin from James Padolsey helps you: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/shuffle-dom-elements/

Simply use it like this:
`$('.my_lis').shuffle();`

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y4kyw/ – Press run to shuffle the list again

Comment: I did not down vote, but note that if that site goes offline, or the URL changes, your answer on Stack Overflow becomes meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the jQuery Sortable plugin which has great examples and code walkthroughs/samples here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SYzk5/)

using

[jQuery plugin to randomly reorder child elements with callback — Gist](https://gist.github.com/236696)

to use: `$(".my_lis").reorder();`